# update progress indicator within javascript function

Tags: javascript, progress

(Please see update at bottom)

I've looked at dozens of questions and haven't been able to make this work.

Given the code below, how can I force it to update my simple progress indicator ($("#log")) after each iteration?

**edit:** I think this JSFiddle exemplifies my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/kPRky/

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="log"></div>
```

This is how the function is being called:

```
$("#test").html(createLevelMap());
```

And this is the function

```
function createLevelMap() {
    var height = 300;
    var width = 1000;
    var totalpixels = height * width; //used for calculating loading percentages;
    var currentpixel = 0; //used for calculating loading percentages;

    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    //lots of other variables

    for (x = 0; x < width; x += 1) {
        for (y = 0; y < height; y += 1) {

            //lots of calculations with lots of variables

            currentpixel += 1;
            $("#log").html((currentpixel / totalpixels) * 100 + "%");
        }
    }

    return ('done'); //actually returns a very long base64 encoded string
}
```

**update**

I simplified it down so that I have a separate function that renders each column, instead of the entire grid.  However, using setTimeout still doesn't result in displaying the progress properly.

```
for (x = 0; x < width; x += 1) {
    $("#log").html(((x + 1) / width) * 100 + "%<br>(sliver " + (x + 1) + "/" + width + ")");
    setTimeout(createSliver(x), 100);
}
```

^^ this results in the output I expect, but no percentage update.  I changed it to setTimeout(function() { createSliver(x) }, 100); as recommended in the comments and then I don't even get my output (also still doesn't increment percentage).

Comment: does this update $("#log") at all?

Comment: After it's finished it displays "100%"

Comment: I saw your original code and it looks like you simplified it, but I _assume_ `totalpixels = width * height`?

Comment: yes, sorry.  I'll add that back

Comment: No worries. I'd also initialize `currentpixel` in your example too, otherwise pedantics will ensue.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that this code is being run synchronously, are you doing any document.writing() in your code, or is there anything that forces the code to run before the DOM can complete?

Comment: Nope, and I updated my question to expand upon all my code from HTML to the function.

Comment: The code just runs fast so you end up at 100. Guessing you should look at setInterval method?

Comment: You might want to use a `setTimeout` sort of pattern where you execute a single increment of currentPixel via a function like this, then use setTimeout to call the function again.

Comment: I've looked at setTimeout and setInterval but haven't been able to properly implement them in this situation.

Comment: @BradChristie, shouldn't it be *pedantry will ensue*?

Comment: Throw in some console.log in the loop and check the values

Comment: With your most recent update, you aren't really calling your function with setTimeout.  You are instead calling your function, then passing its result into setTimeout. Your call should be something like: `setTimeout(function () { createSliver(x) }, 100);`  And you also probably want to use a shorter delay.

Comment: What are your browser support requirements? This task is a poster child for Web Workers.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer: When I do that it doesn't display the image at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to use Web Workers. This lets you run your processing in a completely different thread to the UI updates. If you need to support browsers without web workers you need to use setTimeout to give the GUI update a chance to run.

If using the timeout method you'll get the best experience by setting a max time you'll let it run before breaking out of your loop and calling setTimeout. This will let the GUI repaint.

An example is here : http://jsfiddle.net/kPRky/6/

You can speed it up/slow it down by adding/removing zeros in the somethingSlow method.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var height = 300;
var width = 1000;
var totalpixels = height * width; //used for calculating loading percentages;
var currentpixel = 0; //used for calculating loading percentages;

incrementAndUpdate(currentpixel, totalpixels);

function incrementAndUpdate(currentValue, totalPixels) {
    $("#log").html((currentValue / totalPixels) * 100 + "%");
    if (currentValue < totalPixels) {
        setTimeout(function () { incrementAndUpdate(currentValue + 1, totalPixels); }, 1);
    }
}
```

​

Given the slow speed of this, I suggest that you maybe call this with less frequency and do more work units with each attempt at a setTimeout/html update call.  Maybe create a queue of work to do, and in your `incrementAndUpdate` function, choose to either call the function directly, or via setTimeout.

Something like so...

```
function incrementAndUpdate(currentValue, totalPixels) {
    $("#log").html((currentValue / totalPixels) * 100 + "%");

    // do a bit of work.

    if (currentValue < totalPixels) {
        var workFunction = function () { incrementAndUpdate(currentValue + 1, totalPixels); }
        if (currentValue % 100 == 0)
            setTimeout(workFunction, 1);
        else
            workFunction();
    }
}
```

This does the same amount of work, but it does it faster with fewer `setTimeout` calls.  You could tweak the frequency with which the setTimeout is called in order to optimize the user experience as much as possible.

Here's an update to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kPRky/1/

Comment: the problem is that every "workFunction" needs to use multiple values from the previous iteration.

Comment: Why is that a problem?  Pass those values into the new function call.  There's never more than one of these running concurrently, so there shouldn't be a problem with each one passing info to the next.  Or even using values from a closure, or even globally available data.

Answer (score 0):

So I got the progress to update by calling the setTimeout() function from within itself.  This was the key I was missing.

Here is the basic format now:

```
function nextRow() {
    x += 1;
    setTimeout(function () { createSliver() }, 100);
    if (x < width) { setTimeout(function () { nextRow() }, 100); }
}

function createSliver() {
    //do stuff here
    currentpixel += 1;
    $("#log").html(((currentpixel) / totalpixels) * 100 + "%<br>(pixel " + (currentpixel) + "/" + totalpixels + ")");
    y += 1;
    if (y < height) {
        setTimeout(function () { createSliver() }, 100);
    } else {
        y = 0;
    }

function mainFunction() {
        setTimeout(function () { nextRow() }, 100);
        return (data);
}
```

But now my "data" isn't coming back properly. I'm assuming because everything is running asynchronously now...  poop.